# OS Installation on SSD and storage on HDD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd, operating-systems

I have an Dell 15z 5523 laptop with 32GB SSD and 500 GB HDD. I want to boot my OS from the SSD but use the HDD for storage , i.e. Programs Files, Users etc. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question has been asked before.

[Migrate to SSD - NTFS mount point for Program Files](https://superuser.com/questions/214573/migrate-to-ssd-ntfs-mount-point-for-program-files)

Also, google the term "mount point" along with windows and program files, there are plenty resources. I only have experience with unix in this.

Food for though: by mounting Program Files to a HDD you are eliminating the very reason why an ssd is useful: accessing frequently used applications with near-instant access. I would consider getting a 120GB+ size ssd or, if there are alternatives to your windows programmes, using a linux distro. My home debian install with xfce barely takes up 10gb altogether. You also might want to look into SSD drives lifetimes, as the less space you leave open on an SSD, the less space it has to cycle the written bits around for load-balancing the NAND gates. Thus, it breaks earlier. That's a problem with small drives like your 32gb.